# Subtract column-specific value for a particular row from all values in data frame, in R

Tags: r, matrix, subtraction

I have a data object *signal* in R with 40,000+ rows (named variables) of numeric values and 200+ columns (samples). For every row of each column, I want to subtract the value for the row named *background* for that column.

The code below can be used to create an example *signal* object in R. With the example, for column A, the *background* value of 4 is to be subtracted from the values of *channelNo1* to *3*. Similarly, for column B, the value of 6 is to be subtracted. And so on. What is the simplest way to achieve this in R?

```
text <- textConnection('
             A   B   C
channelNo1  12  22  32
channelNo2  13  21  33
channelNo3  12  21  30
background   4   6   8
')
signal <- read.table(text, header = TRUE)
close(text)

typeof(signal)
# returns 'list'

class(signal)
# returns 'data.frame'
```

Comment: Try providing a small [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/324364) example that others can use to demonstrate an answer.

Comment: Just a note but you have the data back to front as far as most of R is concerned. Rows are samples/observations, columns are the variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements in an R matrix are oriented by column (check out `matrix(1:12, nrow=3)` and `signal - signal[4,]` is not doing what you think -- check out column B, where the second and third values should be the same (and equal to 15). You could write

```
as.data.frame(Map("-", signal, as.vector(signal[4,])))
```

(I think this would be relatively efficient) but since the data really seem to be a matrix (i.e., a rectangle of homogeneous type) it makes a lot more sense to manipulate it as a matrix

```
m = as.matrix(signal)
sweep(m, 2, m[4,], "-")
```

Comment: Both of your suggestions work. Thank you, and also for pointing out the incorrectness I had in the example code. I have removed it.